# jquery - x-editable - reset 'new record' after submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have been trying to figure this out for hours to no avail.

I have the following

http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/docs.html#newrecord

the new record module/code. Its functionality is, once all the rows have their data, and it is submitted, it retains its value so that it can stay editable.

I have tried adding input, select clearing code in the success of the ajax request and tried putting the .editable function inside an ajaxComplete function to see if it would reload the element on submit but it didnt. look at the demo. enter data, and submit. it then makes the data "permanent" so that it can continue to be editable.

I have removed the code that hides the button.

What i want it to do is, submit the record and reset so i can submit another with the form being 'Empty' and back to default.

I am developing an equipment tracker and would love if techs could just enter records, one after another. im sure its a simple fix to reset the form, i just cannot figure it out.

I have attached a screencast video of it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPDuQCgOOSw

Comment: P.S. it is not 'really' a form. if you review the code on the first link above in element inspector you will see its just a few inputs that are recognized by their designated editable class and that is how they are submitted.

Comment: anyone? :\ I really need to figure out how to reset this element.

Comment: im assuming that you are supposed to implement a reset button?

Comment: of sorts i suppose. its not a "form" so that would be difficult. if you look at the first link at the Creating New Record code, i want it to "reset" once the data is submitted. instead of retaining submitted values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as it's popular question, I've added Reset button to documentation.

```
$('#reset-btn').click(function() {
    $('.myeditable').editable('setValue', null) //clear values
        .editable('option', 'pk', null)         //clear pk
        .removeClass('editable-unsaved');       //remove bold css

    $('#save-btn').show();
    $('#msg').hide();
});
```

It's better to use `.editable('setValue', null)` instead of `.text('Empty')` as we need also to reset internal value.
HTH

Comment: now we are getting somewhere. now the issue is that fields that are "text" inputs are taking on the value of null instead of "empty". here is a demo http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLF4maCETsk

Comment: also, when it sets the <a> link to null, it bypasses validation as well. not sure what the issue is.

Comment: fixed it temporarily by doing this $("a#serial").addClass('editable-empty').text('Empty'); but for some reason it still fails validation. may need to move revalidate code to ajaxComplete so it reloads.

Comment: I've create jsfiddle that works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/K4k9a/3/  Could you modify it as in your code to find a bug? thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you look how the "save new user `button`" is implemented, it just selects the anchor tags that have classname `myeditable`

Either you bind a function to your 'reset' button or have this script `onclick`

```
IF onclick:

jQuery.each($('.myeditable'),function() { 
    $(this).text('Empty') ; //this is your default text
});

OR as a function

function reset_myeditable()
{
    jQuery.each($('.myeditable'),function() { 
        $(this).text('Empty') ; //this is your default text
    });
}
```

and attach this to the `onclick` handler of your `reset` button
This I assume you will be putting a 'reset' button

EDIT

Ok zoom in to your `$('#save-btn').click(function() success handler`

```
    success: function(data, config) {
    if(data && data.id) {  //record created, response like {"id": 2}

    $(this).editable('option', 'pk', data.id);
    //remove unsaved class
    $(this).removeClass('editable-unsaved');
    //show messages
    var msg = 'New user created! Now editables submit individually.';
    $('#msg').addClass('alert-success').removeClass('alert-error').html(msg).show();
    $('#save-btn').hide(); 
    $(this).off('save.newuser'); 

/**this the edited part**/
  jQuery.each($('.myeditable'),function() { 
     $(this).text('Empty') ; //this is your default text
  });
/**end of edit**/      

} else if(data && data.errors){ 
           //server-side validation error, response like {"errors": {"username": "username already exist"} }
           config.error.call(this, data.errors);
       }               
   },
```

Comment: no need for a reset button, i will run the 'reset' on form ajax success. here is a link to the new revision. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMegyAhhSxk

Comment: it seems the popup fields are retaining their value even if the <td> element is "Empty"

Comment: it is in 720p, set the video to 720 and make it fullscreen and pause. i didnt change much from the original code from the first site. only disabled it from hiding the submit button, and removed the success alert.

Comment: here is a live edit on the demo site using your code. it changes the text, but not the 'cached' input form data. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GPTyLAItrU