# angular x-editable deselecting selection to clear text input not working

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

UPDATE: changing post to a more simplified example.

http://jsfiddle.net/bphein1980/avfozhx4/1/

QUESTION: When the x-editable selection is changed to "option3" and the $scope.condition1value is set to zero (0) in $scope.changeCondition1()... why is the view not reflecting the new condition1value value?

Code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">

        <form editable-form name="myForm">
            <button class="show" type="button" ng-show="!myForm.$visible" ng-click="myForm.$show()">Edit</button>
            <button class="done" type="submit" ng-show="myForm.$visible">Done</button>
        </form>

        <span 
            editable-select="condition1" 
            e-ng-options="c1.name as c1.name for c1 in condition1s" 
            e-ng-change="changeCondition1($data)"
            e-form="myForm"
            e-name="condition1"
        >
            {{ showCondition1() }}
        </span>

        <span editable-text="condition1value" e-ng-model="condition1value" e-name="condition1value" e-form="myForm"> 
            {{ condition1value }}
        </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

More code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["xeditable"]);

myApp.run(function(editableOptions, editableThemes) {
    editableOptions.theme = 'default'; 
});

myApp.controller("testController", ["$scope", "$filter", testController]);

function testController($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.condition1s = [
        { id: 1, name: "option1" },
        { id: 2, name: "option2" },
        { id: 3, name: "option3" }
    ];

    $scope.condition1 = "";
    $scope.condition1value = "20";

    $scope.changeCondition1 = function(newVal){
        if(newVal == 'option3'){
             $scope.condition1value = 0;   
        }
        console.log("changeCondition1", newVal, $scope);
    };

    $scope.showCondition1 = function(){
        var selected = $filter('filter')($scope.condition1s, { name: $scope.currentCondition1 });
        return ($scope.currentCondition1 && selected.length) ? selected[0].name : 'empty';        
    };

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to work out a solution. Xeditable creates it's own scope when editing and then copies it back when done. You can edit the form's scope directly.

Here is a working sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/bphein1980/0au7h389/

In the fiddle view, edit a line and change the selection to "empty". The value in the text field to the right of it will be removed.

```
$scope.changeCondition2 = function(data, line){
    line.condition2 = data;
    if(data === ''){
        var editables = this.$form.$editables;
        for(var i=0; i<=editables.length-1; i++){
           if(editables[i].name == 'condition2value'){
               editables[i].scope.$data = ""; 
               break;
           }
        }
    }
};
```

This is the post that helped me find the solution:
https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/60

Comment: +1 for sharing your findings! It works. ...but it's a mess. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036336/jquery-x-editable-reset-new-record-after-submit/14042384#14042384) shows a jQuery implementation, but I cannot find a solution for Angular. Perhaps @vitalets can offer a solution?

Comment: For a pure angular solution, and not modding anything, it works well enough to use.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking, but have you tried invoking a $watch in your controller to see when the model you're listening to is null or empty then it will set all the proper fields the way you need it to be?

Could you say the question in another way since it doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: When a select is deselected (empty option selected), I want the text input to be empty as well. In my fiddle, if you click the edit button on one of the rows, change the bottom selected to empty... I want the text input to the right of it to be emptied as well. The console log shows that it is, but it is not reflected in the view. I am obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: Putting a watch on $scope.lines shows that it is updated, but the view does not reflect it. The value in the text box still remains.

Comment: I mean tertiary inspection of your code seems like there are no $scope variables... How are you binding the data between the models and the view?

Comment: yeah I saw that, but if you look at your code... you're applying lines.conditionblahblah = ' '; So, that's not how you set variables in $scope for databinding, correct me if I am wrong. You might want to rework this whole thing and give your drop downs and inputs models after the $scope object your working with. There is no databinding going on here.

Comment: can you provide a small example? I have tried updating the $scope.lines[index].condition2value directly in the change function... and it does not update it either. However, I can change the values in the view, click done, and all is good. I just need for the selection to change the data when empty. Really, I am not sure what is wrong... pretty new to angular, so please forgive my ignorance. Been looking through examples and what not, the best example I found is http://jsfiddle.net/leeray75/jwv29g1m/... when the status changes the group on a certain selected value.